# Selenium can't find by element

Tags: selenium

I try to scroll down by element class. I need to scroll by tweet in twitter.com

```
from time import sleep

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('http://twitter.com/elonmusk')
sleep(5)

while True:
    html = driver.find_element_by_class_name('css-901oao r-1fmj7o5 r-1qd0xha r-a023e6 r-16dba41 r-rjixqe r-bcqeeo r-bnwqim r-qvutc0')
    html.send_keys(Keys.END)
```

I have error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: .css-901oao r-1fmj7o5 r-1qd0xha r-a023e6 r-16dba41 r-rjixqe r-bcqeeo r-bnwqim r-qvutc0
```

Comment: What does this represent in UI `css-901oao r-1fmj7o5 r-1qd0xha r-a023e6 r-16dba41 r-rjixqe r-bcqeeo r-bnwqim r-qvutc0` ?

Comment: tweet text area, where tag span with text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That class name have spaces in your code, `class_name` does not work with spaces, try the below **xpath** :

```
//div[@data-testid='tweet']
```

and you can write like this in code :

```
counter = 1
while True:
    html = driver.find_element_by_xpath(f"(//div[@data-testid='tweet'])[{counter}]")
    counter =  counter  + 1
    html.send_keys(Keys.END)
```

Comment: selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element <div class="css-1dbjc4n r-18u37iz"> is not reachable by keyboard

Comment: You need to launch the browser in full screen node as well as you may have to use ActionsChain. Can you tell me what exactly you wanna do twitter ?

Comment: I wanna parse text from last 20 tweets(only text)

Comment: You meant to say you wanna retrieve last 20 tweets from twitter ?